# h2o GLM R Dipersion parameter

Tags: r, h2o, glm

Is there a way to extract the dispersion parameter (also called `phi`) from an `h2o.glm()` object?

In standard R this can va achieved by doing

```
summary(glm_object)$dispersion
```

Is it possible to achieve the same with an `h2o.glm()` object?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the dispersion parameter for H2O's GLM model in **Python** it would be `your_glm_model._model_json['output']['dispersion']`
And in **R** it would be `attr(your_glm_model, 'model')$dispersion` or `your_glm_model@model$dispersion`